# Creating a directory in custom command after Monodevelop builds the project in Windows XP

Tags: copy, windows-xp, monodevelop, mkdir, xamarin-studio

I'm developing a project using `Monodevelop` 4 in Windows XP and I need to copy some of the `.dll` library files into some folder after they are built. These libraries are plugins to a main project and so the main project is not depended on them and they need to be copied manually.

But as we are using computers nothing needs to actually be done manually, and so I turned to Monodevelop's `Custom Commands` in project settings. There I can type in any command I like (supposedly).

So here's what I did; First I added a command to make sure the destination folder exists:

```
mkdir "${SolutionDir}\MainProj\bin\${ProjectConfigName}\Plugins"
```

And then copied the library:

```
xcopy "${TargetFile}" "${SolutionDir}\MainProj\bin\${ProjectConfigName}\Plugins" /Y
```

But the thing is that the first command fails and so the second one never executes. To see the results of the first command I checked both of checkboxes named `Run on external console` and `Pause console ouput` and here's its output:

```
'"mkdir"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

In IDE's output panel I can read `mkdir "C:\Some\Path\MainProj\bin\Debug\Plugins"` which is correct and when I paste it into a console creates the folder successfully so I have no idea why Monodevelop is unable to execute it!

Does anyone have any comment on this problem?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Don't have any XP machine. But what about little hack? Create a dir named "Plugins" in your main project. Put arbitrary text file (README.txt) into it -> right click on file -> quick properties -> copy to output directory. This will create directory named "Plugins" in your target directory.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion but I managed to solve the problem using a batch file. I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution myself. I created a `batch` file with `mkdir` command in it and called it in the project's `Custom Commands`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this in Xamarin Studio (ver 4.2.5) by using `xcopy` instead of `copy` and providing the full path to `xcopy.exe`:

```
"%systemroot%\system32\xcopy.EXE" /y "${ProjectDir}\myAppSettings.config" "${TargetDir}"
```

After some experimentation, it appears that Xamarin Studio/MonoDevelop:

1. Wraps the entire *custom command* in double-quotes, and
2. Includes logic to try to deal with you "improperly" including additional double-quotes. (I tried an injection technique to undo the quotation.)

This has the side effect of rendering [internal shell commands](http://blog.brainasoft.com/2013/06/all-internal-commands-of-cmd.html) unexecutable - because `copy` becomes `"copy"`, which isn't a valid command. And it explains why moving everything to a batch file also resolves the issue - there is now a physical file (which a physical path) to execute.